# VBA to change selection on a Power Query Table Slicer

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery, slicers

I have been stuck on this all day and would really appreciate some help.

I have a table which I created in Power Query and have loaded this into an Excel worksheet named "Pay Com".  To this table, I have added 2 slicers - one for Job and the other for Country.  The filters work fine on the table.

I am trying to add VB code where I can change the slicer selections based on named ranges. So I want the Job slicer to be the value in my named range Filter_Job and the Country slicer to be the value in my named range 'Filter_Country'

I am not that proficient in VBA, but I have used code previously to change slicers in pivot tables.  However, I cannot get this slicer to work and I don't know why.  Is it something to do with the slicer being tied to a table rather than a pivot table?  (The Report Connection option is greyed out if that has any implications).

Any guidance would be really appreciated.

I tried a couple of methods after googling this.  I tried .SlicerCaches and it didn't like it.  I tried .Shapes and it didn't work
I have passed the variables and set my variable values.  It is the end part where I try to filter the slicer it does not work

This is my current code:
The first part of this code is dealing with double clicking within a pivot table, extracting values from the position of the double-clicked cell and pasting those into the named cells.
The second part of the code is what I need help with.  I want to take the values from these named cells and use them to filter my slicers for a table that has been loaded from Power Query.  It seems the table being from Power Query is the issue I am facing?

I have incorporated the code as per your answer @Taller but that still does not seem to work.  It needs debugging at this line: countryValue = "|" & Join(Application.Transpose(Range("Filter_NH_Country")), "|") & "|"

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim wsHeatMap As Worksheet
    Dim wsCom As Worksheet

    Dim SI As SlicerItem
    Dim jcValue As String
    Dim countryValue As String
    
    
    ' Set references to the specific worksheets & Table
    Set wsHeatMap = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("NH Map")
    Set wsCom = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Pay Com")
    
    
    ' Check if only one cell is selected in pivot table
    If Target.Count = 1 Then
        ' Check if the double click happened in a PivotTable
        On Error Resume Next
        Set pt = Target.PivotTable
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        If Not pt Is Nothing And pt.Name = "pvt_Map" Then
            ' This is my specific pivot table
            ' Adjust the logic as needed, Example: Cancel the double click
            Cancel = True
    
    ' Extract values from position of my selected cell
    jcValue = Cells(Target.Row, "D").Value
    countryValue = Cells(10, Target.Column - 1).Value
            
    ' Place the extracted values in the named ranges
    Range("Filter_Job").Value = jcValue
    Range("Filter_Country").Value = countryValue
        
    ' Reset error handling
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    jcValue = Range("Filter_Job").Value
    countryValue = Range("Filter_Country").Value
    
    
    ' Apply filters to slicers in the "Pay Comp" worksheet
    
    ***countryValue = "|" & Join(Application.Transpose(Range("Filter_NH_Country")), "|") & "|"***
    For Each SI In wsCom.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Country1").SlicerItems
        SI.Selected = InStr(1, countryValue, "|" & SI.Name & "|")
    Next
    jobValue = "|" & Join(Application.Transpose(Range("Filter_NH_JC")), "|") & "|"
    For Each SI In wsComp.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Job_Code").SlicerItems
        SI.Selected = InStr(1, jobValue, "|" & SI.Name & "|")
    Next
        
        
        End If
        
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: I would recommend bypassing the need for slicers entirely by importing your cell values into power query and using them to filter the data before it's loaded to the worksheet.

Comment: Please provide details on the code you attempted, and explain on the specific issues you encountered.

Comment: Thank you for the responses.  @MichaelMurphy I am only starting in my Excel Data Model journey so that proficient to know how to pass the values to Power Query.  My aim in trying to filter the data table is that I want to create a scatter chart and I cannot do that from a pivot table.  The results of the filtered table allow me to create the chart I need.

Comment: @Taller I added your code in what I already have and it doesn't seem to like that first line for the filtering of the table. I get the Compile Error: Method or data member not found.   I am adding the code I have and will explain what I am trying to do as it includes more than the issue I am trying to solve for.

Answer (score 0):

- Assuming slicers are named `Slicer_Country` and `Slicer_Job`

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [SlicerItem.Selected property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.sliceritem.selected?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm907079)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [InStr function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1008946)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```vb
Sub DEMO()
    Dim oSI As SlicerItem
    Dim sFilterCou As String, sFilterJob As String
    sFilterCou = "|" & Join(Application.Transpose(Range("Filter_Country")), "|") & "|"
    For Each oSI In ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Country").SlicerItems
        oSI.Selected = InStr(1, sFilterCou, "|" & oSI.Name & "|")
    Next
    sFilterJob = "|" & Join(Application.Transpose(Range("Filter_Job")), "|") & "|"
    For Each oSI In ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Job").SlicerItems
        oSI.Selected = InStr(1, sFilterJob, "|" & oSI.Name & "|")
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I am double-clicking into a pivot value and I want the code to first bypass the error I will get (I have disabled the get data option in the pivot table).  Then I ask the code to get the value from column D in the same row I clicked and put into the range "Filter_NH_JC" and then get the value from row 10 and 1 column to the left and put that value into the range "Filter_NH_Country".  So far, that all works fine.  Then these 2 values are what I want to use to filter the slicers that I have in another sheet in the same workbook. Those slicers are connected to a table loaded from power query

Comment: Please share smaple data and data layout on sheet in your original post.

Comment: Apologies.  I was trying to comment back with the code I was using but couldn't fit that into a comment box.  I have edited by original post to include this now

Comment: What's the error number and text? What's the shape of `Filter_NH_Country`? in a Row? in a Col?